# unable to pass value in python & selenium automation

Tags: python, selenium

I'm unable to pass the numeric value on both Id and name tag. But work fine with other fields only error with cnic field.

```
<input class="cnic_new form-control" id="ac_cnic" name="ac_cnic" onchange="CheckSepcialCharacter(this);" onkeypress="EnterPressed(this,event);" size="30" type="text">
```

Here is the code for python with selenium automation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Option
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
s = Service("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Downloads\\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ac_cnic']").send_keys("3230150828555")
```

After successfully running the program I'm not getting any value because of JavaScript.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ac_cnic' and @name='ac_cnic']")
input_box.send_keys("3230150828555")
```

- Check by selecting the element using both the arguments.
  In the given picture is showing the input box is containing two separator"-".
- Maybe the keys are not filling in the box properly.
  Try to send keys in parts if still getting same error.

like -

```py
input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ac_cnic' and @name='ac_cnic']")

# Try to fill manually once to understand if the value are entering in a separation or no. According to that choose the following sequence. 
input_box.send_keys("32301")
input_box.send_keys("50828")
input_box.send_keys("555")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `explicitWait` for entering the value in the input field. As you mentioned that this particular field you are not getting

```
cnicNumber = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='ac_cnic']")))
cnicNumber.send_keys("546638394")

OR

Also, try to check with the XPath
//input[@id='ac_cnic' and @type='text']

cnicNumber = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='ac_cnic' and @type='text']")))
cnicNumber.send_keys("546638394")
```